# WIX: Error localisation

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have the code:

```
 <Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1049"  Codepage="1251">
    <Package  InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Description="N"/>
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Тест">
              <Directory Id="Videomarket" Name="Настройки"/>
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
```

In pointing out the project properties:

[image]

MSI Project compile success.

But when choosing the type of project Executable Package (.exe) receive an error:

> A string was provided with characters that are not available in the
>   specified database code page '1252'. Either change these characters to
>   ones that exist in the database's code page, or update the database's
>   code page by modifying one of the following attributes:
>   Product/@Codepage, Module/@Codepage, Patch/@Codepage,
>   PatchCreation/@Codepage, or WixLocalization/@Codepage.

and the property is not active:
[image]

Why is this happening and how to deal with it?

Comment: It is highly possible that you have non-english characters in the wix files. It could be dialogues, warning messages...any string.

Comment: I see that you are using a language id for Russian but the code page used is that of ANSI Latin 1. Maybe you want to use an appropirate code page value to accomodate the characters used. Take a look at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx for a list of available code pages that might accomodate the characters used.